# Email non blank values on form submit

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, triggers, html-email, google-forms

I have a sheet with around 50 columns and am attempting to email the non blank fields in HTML format to a user; but only the NON-Blank fields, here's my code, which returns Null and Non-Null fields, plus I need it to only email out the last form submission, not all of them:

```
      function onFormSubmit(e) {
      var ss = e.source;
      var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();          
      var range = e.range.getA1Notation();
      var column = e.range.getColumn();
      var row = e.range.getRow();
      var values = e.namedValues;
      var htmlBody = '<ul>';
      for (Key in values) {
        var label = Key;
        var data = values[Key];
        htmlBody += '<li>' + label + ": " + data + '</li>';
       };
       htmlBody += '</ul>'
     var Submitter = 3;
     var Submitteremail = sheet.getRange(row,Submitter).getValue();

  MailApp.sendEmail({
         to: "Jason@xxxx.com", 
         replyTo: Submitteremail, 
         subject, 
         htmlBody : htmlBody});
 Logger.log("checkpoint5");
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my appended code after your initial help:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
const sh=e.range.getSheet();          
var htmlBody='<ol>';
var Url = "https://docs.google.com/xxx";
var Text = "CMF Form Submission Sheet";
for(key in e.namedValues) {
  if(e.namedValues[key][0].length>0) {
    htmlBody += '<li>' + key + ": " + e.namedValues[key][0] + '</li>';
 }
}
htmlBody += '<p>' + '\n' + '\n' + "<a href=\""+ Url + "\">" + Text + "</a>" + 
'\n' + '\n' + '\n' + '<p>' + '</ol>' ;
var Submitteremail = e.values[1];
var Type = e.values[6];
var CMFNumber = e.values[0];
var Sub = "A new CMF has been submitted for a " + Type;
MailApp.sendEmail({to:"Jason.@xxx.com",subject: Sub, replyTo:Submitteremail, 
htmlBody:htmlBody});
Logger.log(html);
}
```

Comment: This is great!   I ended up changing things a bit; but how do I keep the Column headers in order left to right as they get emailed out?

Comment: How about not removing the blanks and use a normal for loop or forEach with a header array.  `const headerArray=sh.getRange(1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues().flat();` and then e.values.forEach((v,i)=>{html+='<li>' + headerArray[i] + ':' + v + '</li>';});`

Comment: that's some intense code!   I don't really know where to use that code or what to replace with it

Comment: It's just a loop and it's printing them in the order that they are in the form

Comment: Where would I use that in my code then?  above the IF statement ? or in place of it ?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know how to answer other than  to say wherever you think you need it.